# JavaFX Application in IntelliJ IDEA Cannot Find CSS File in Resources

Tags: java, css, intellij-idea, javafx

**Issue Description:**
I am developing a JavaFX application using IntelliJ IDEA and encountering an issue where the application does not locate a CSS file placed in the resources folder.

In my project, there's a **`style.css`** file located under **`src/main/resources/view`**. Despite this, when attempting to load it in my JavaFX application with **`getClass().getResource("/view/style.css")`**, it consistently returns **`null`**.

**Relevant Code Implementation:**

```
public class MainGui extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(new DocumentSelectionView());

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1400, 900);

        // Attempting to load the CSS file
        scene.getStylesheets().clear();
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")); // Prints the project directory

        // Different methods tried to add the stylesheet
        // Method 1
        scene.getStylesheets().add("src/main/resources/view/style.css"); 
        // Method 2
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/view/style.css").toExternalForm()); 
    }
}
```

**Problems Encountered:**

1. **Method 1** (**`scene.getStylesheets().add("src/main/resources/view/style.css");`**):

   - Results in the warning:
     **`WARNING: Resource "src/main/resources/view/style.css" not found.`**
2. **Method 2** (**`scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/view/style.css").toExternalForm());`**):

   - Returns **`null`**, leading to an error when attempting to call **`.toExternalForm()`**.

**Additional Information:**

- The project directory is correctly printed, confirming the working directory.
- I have verified that there are no typographical errors in the file path.
- The CSS file certainly exists in the specified directory.
- The CSS file is not in the target output folder.
- I am using IntelliJ IDEA for my project structure, not Maven or Gradle. Here is the relevant content from my **`.iml`** file:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module version="4">
    <component name="AdditionalModuleElements">
      <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$" dumb="true">
        <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
        <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
        <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
        <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
      </content>
    </component>
  </module>
  ```

**Question:**

What could be causing this failure to locate the **`style.css`** file, and how can I correctly load it into my JavaFX application?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Attempts:**

I have attempted several approaches to resolve the issue where **`getResource()`** consistently returns **`null`**. Here's a summary of the steps I've taken:

- Replicated the issue in other classes across different packages, encountering the same problem with **`getResource()`** returning **`null`**.
- Tried various strings to locate the CSS file, including:

  - **`"style.css"`**
  - **`"/style.css"`**
  - **`"view/style.css"`**
  - **`"/view/style.css"`**
- Moved the CSS file directly into the **`resources`** folder.
- Experimented with different CSS file names and methods of creating these files.
- Restarted IntelliJ IDEA.
- Rebuilt the entire software.
- Invalidated the cache in IntelliJ IDEA and performed a restart (I do this after every change just to be sure).
- I did try replicating this in other classes of other packages. The getRecource() always returns null.
- To Settings -> Compiler -> Resource patterns I've added `!?*.css`
- `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/view/style.css");`
- Moving the resource folder directly in the project folder /src/main/resources -> /resources

Comment: I haven’t worked directly with IntelliJ configuration in the iml file (I use Maven), but the resources folder is not usually considered a source folder. Source folders contain Java files which are *compiled* to the target folder. Resources are in resource folders and are simply *copied* to the target folder. I don’t know if iml files support a `<resourceFolder>` element but you need something like that.

Comment: If you check your output folder, you presumably will find that `view/style.css` doesn’t exist there. Once you fix the configuration so that it’s correctly copied to the output/target, `getClass().getResource(“/view/style.css”).toExternalForm()` will work.

Comment: The file doesn't exist in the outputfolder indeed. I've moved the resource folder to the main project folder like this:
'<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/resources" type="java-resource" />'
It still generates null and is't in the outpout folder. I am gonna try recreating everything in a new Maven project but I have no experience using Maven yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To Settings -> Compiler -> Resource patterns I've added !?*.css"

You don't want to do that.

That treats `.css` files as *NOT* resources.  That is the opposite of what you want.

Note though that (I think) the compiler setting is just for handling files under directories marked as `Sources`, and won't affect files that are marked as `Resources`.  From my tests, `.css` files under directories I marked a `Resources` were always copied to the output directory, regardless of the `Compiler | Resource patterns` setting. So it likely isn't the root cause of your issue.

**Working example**

I tried:

- creating a new Java project (not JavaFX project) in Idea with generated sample code (using the Idea new Java project wizard).
- [manually setting a resource path in the IDE for the module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#configure-folders).
- Placing a css resource file in the resource directory I configured.
- Modified sample java code in the src directory to lookup the resource.

By default (with no other change) it the `.css` file I put in the resource directory I created was copied to the build output directory and could be found by a `getResource` lookup as expected.

After building:

```
<projectdir>/out/production/<modulename>/
```

Contained these files:

```
Main.class
styles.class
```

[image: resources]

*/src/Main.java*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        System.out.println(Main.class.getResource("/styles.css"));
    }
}
```

*/resources/styles.css*

```
.root {
    -fx-base: mistyrose;
}
```

*Output*

```
Hello world!
file:/C:/dev/resourcetest/out/production/resourcetest/styles.css
```

*Settings | Compile | Resource patterns*

These are defaults for a new Java project with Idea 2023.2.4 (UE), I didn't change them:

```
!?*.java
!?*.form
!?*.class
!?*.groovy
!?*.scala
!?*.flex
!?*.kt
!?*.clj
!?*.aj
```

**Recommendation**

Using a build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle), following the [Maven standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), and synching the build project with your IDE is usually a better approach than manually configuring the project in the IDE.

Comment: Absolutely deserved 'like' for "Using a build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle)". This is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the responses and the help provided!

After reviewing your feedback, I got confirmation that the problem wasn't with the code itself but rather with the project setup in IntelliJ. The exact cause within the setup remained elusive, but I found a solution by taking a different approach.

I decided to rebuild the project using Maven. A key part of this process was correctly setting up the VM arguments for JavaFX, which was initially challenging due to the scattered dependencies. Once these were properly configured, the application successfully recognized and loaded the CSS file.

Reconstructing the project in Maven proved to be the effective solution I needed. Thank you all for your assistance.

For those having the same problem and want to use maven aswell here are my setup files:

1. `pom.xml`

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>DDoc</groupId>
       <artifactId>SummerEase_Maven</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

       <properties>
           <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
           <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
           <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
           <javafx.version>21.0.1</javafx.version> <!-- JavaFX version -->
       </properties>

       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
               <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
               <version>1.18.30</version>
           </dependency>
           <!-- JavaFX dependencies -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
               <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
               <version>21.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
               <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
               <version>21.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
               <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
               <version>21.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
               <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
               <version>21.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
               <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
               <version>21.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
               <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
               <version>21.0.1</version>
           </dependency>
           <!-- Add other dependencies as needed -->
       </dependencies>

   </project>
   ```
2. VM argument to be able to run javafx

   ```
   --module-path
   /home/guillaume/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/21.0.1/:/home/guillaume/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/21.0.1/:/home/guillaume/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/21.0.1/:/home/guillaume/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/21.0.1/
   --add-modules
   javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics
   ```

   You need to add `:` between all your javafx folders so that all correct jars are selected.

Comment: Note that `:` is used as the separator for Linux and macOS. For Windows, use `;`.

Comment: You shouldn't have to deal with `--module-path` (and possibly not `--add-modules`, not sure) directly if using Maven. Try applying OpenJFX's [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin) plugin. Then you should be able to run the application in your development environment by executing the `javafx:run` Maven goal (and it should ideally "just work"). You can add a run configuration to IntelliJ to execute this goal from the IDE. Note all build and run tasks should be delegated to the build tool when using one (don't mix the build tool with the IDE's own build systems).

Comment: As an aside, if you're going have a `<javafx.version>21.0.1</javafx.version>` property, then you should make use of the property when declaring JavaFX dependencies. In other words, for the JavaFX dependencies, replace `<version>21.0.1</version>` with `<version>${javafx.version}</version>`. This is useful because then you only have to change the version in one location when you need to, rather than in six locations.

Comment: Additional note regarding `javafx:run`: You have to compile the project first. You can do both at the same time. On the command line, it might look like `mvn compile javafx:run`. You can setup a single run configuration in IntelliJ to do the same thing.